# Writing a Linux driver for a weird keyboard

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver, hid

I own a keyboard that has an anti-ghosting mode.

It is toggled on/off using Fn+ScrollLock. When on, the codes sent are a bit different. The keyboard is still legitimate HID, but, for example, all modifier keys are seen by Linux as Shift and the actual modifier key is in another field of the event.

What I am looking for is either a ready driver (should someone happen to know about one) or some introduction to writing such input drivers. I do not know much about the ecosystem (evdev, libinput, etc.) and I do not even know where to start. If possible, the same driver should work both under X11 and under Wayland.

Just for the record, the keyboard's “shop” name is Modecom Volcano Gaming. The USB ID is`258a:1006` and it is apparently not annotated in `usb.ids`. The keyboard works perfectly fine in both modes under Windows.

Comment: Looks like you need a specific quirk for this keyboard.